# iCloud Notes show Apple Pencil notes as blank attachments

Tags: icloud, windows, notes.app

[image: iCloud note showing as attachment]

Any guesses if this is possible to overcome. This changed only recently. The notes are showing fine on iPad and iPhone. The browser is Chrome and OS is Windows 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They fixed it today (15th Dec 2022).

Answer (score -2):

For now there seems to be no solution. Try to use only text when you want to see your information on Windows browser.

Comment: This doesn't really solve my issue but you were the only one to look into this.